# Populating values in django-admin based on a foreign key selection ... Again

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I saw the original post [Populating values in django-admin based on a foreign key selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321186/populating-values-in-django-admin-based-on-a-foreign-key-selection) but did not understand the template extending example:

```
    {% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

    {% block extrahead %}
        
        
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id_template').change(function() {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{% url get_template_info %}",
                data: {'template_id': $('#id_template').val()},
                success: function(data, _status) {
                  $('#id_throttle').val(data.throttle);
                  $('#id_rate_limit').val(data.rate_limit);
                  $('#id_product').val(data.product);
                  $('#id_tier_group').val(data.tier_group);
                },
                dataType: "json"
              });               
            });
          });
        
    {% endblock %}
```

I am trying to do something similar, but do not understand where the url get_template_info comes from.

I am assuming should be a method that belongs to TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) but I am not sure about that. the only clue in django documentation was  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ which puts an example

```
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # A template for a very customized change view:
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/openstreetmap_change_form.html'

    def get_osm_info(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_osm_info()
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            extra_context=extra_context)
```

But tend to be more cryptic!, I am new on Django so please give me some guidance on this thing.

Answer (score 1):

The author of that answer wasn't very comprehensive, but there's a hint in the last line:

> which hits a view that simply takes the id passed in, queries it up
>   and returns it to the call. Works like a charm.

`get_template_info` isn't a built in part of Django. It's the name of the view he created to handle the AJAX request. You'll have to create your own view to return the information you need.

Comment: ok thanks. Will try that way. uhmm he is returning json data.. so that view should build that.. so that has sense. Thanks Chris